# generate a 5 char long string 0-9 a-z

Tags: php

I need a function in php that can generate a 5 char long string with numbers and a-z

What should I look into?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Other's have already provided you with correct answers, but here's a one-liner, just for the sake of it:

```
$code = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 0, 5);
```

`str_shuffle` randomizes the above string, then `substr` takes the first 5 letters of that shuffled string. Simple.

---

As noted in comments for this answer, this function only generates strings that have only unique characters. If one would like to have the strings where even "aaaaa" is possible, here's a little function that allows just that:

```
function generate($len) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', $len)), 0, $len);
}

echo generate(5);
```

`str_repeat` repeats the 0-9a-z string $len times, so every letter has an *almost* equal possibility for every position. (Read the comments on why only "almost")

Comment: Doesn't matter how many you know, there will always be a PHP function you never heard of :)

Comment: Elegant solution, although each character will be unique, (e.g. the string 'aa111' wouldn't be a possible result) which may or may not be desirable; the OP didn't specify.

Comment: @Frank Farmer, you're right, I modified my answer to include also a version that creates non-char-unique codes.

Comment: But still the probability for ‘aaaaa’ is lower than that for ‘abcde’…

Comment: If you have five repeats (and thus 5*36=180 letters), drawing an ‘a’ as the first letter has a probability of 5/180=1/36. But for the second letter you will only have 4 ‘a’s left while there are still 5 ‘b’s. So the probability for ‘aa’ is (5/180)*(4/179) and that for ‘ab’ is (5/180)*(5/179) and so on… (So, ‘aaaaa’ is 5^5/5! ≈ 26 times less likely than ‘abcde’.) Basically what you want is drawing with repetition and not just shuffling a larger set.

Comment: @Debilski, you're correct, I'm not very good at probabilities :) But I guess that'll suffice for a while, a truly random string would require a bit more code.

Answer (score 3):

For kicks, here's an alternate approach:

```
//create a random base 36 string
$str = base_convert(rand(), 10, 36);
```

substr and concatenate as necessary to satisfy length requirements.

This will *not* give unique characters (e.g., 'aa11a' would be a possible output) -- which may or may not be what the OP wants.  Also, the fact that you may need to run the function multiple times to get a string of the requested length means performance may not be spectacular, but if you're only calling this function once or twice, it won't matter.
Here's a more complete implementation:

```
function randstr($len) {
  $currLen = 0;
  $value = '';
  while($currLen < $len) {
    $new = base_convert(rand(), 10, 36);
    $value .= $new;
    $currLen += strlen($new);
  }
  //$value may be longer than the requested $len
  return substr($value, 0, $len);
}
```

It's also worth noting that this string will be of less-than-perfect randomness -- the first char of each string output by base_convert will have a bias toward the lower end of the spectrum (as rand() will not completely fill a whole char's worth of bits every time).  Ideally, you want a number of bits out of rand that will exactly fill some number of base-36 chars.

Using a source of entropy that gives you more bits than you need for the string in the first place (like /dev/urandom) would resolve this issue.  But for most applications, the loss of entropy won't matter enough to justify the overhead of reading /dev/urandom.

Alternately, you could simply throw away the first char of each base_convert() call.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a random string?

If so, simply create a string containing the 36 characters, generate 5 random numbers and create the string based on the character positions (pseudo-code):

```
string src = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
string dst = ""
for i = 1 to 5:
    dst = dst + src[random(len(src))]
```

If you want 5 *unique* characters, you do the same thing but with one slight difference.

Generate the first random number in the range 0 through 35, the second in the range 0 through 34 and so on.

Then, as you add the character from the source string to your own string, replace the used character in the source string with the *last* character in the source string. This will prevent the same character from being selected twice:

```
string src = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
int srclen = len(src)
string dst = ""
for i = 1 to 5:
    idx = randon(len(src))
    dst = dst + src[idx]
    src[idx] = src[srclen-1]
    srclen = srclen - 1
```

*Aside:* @Tatu has provided a simple solution using `str_shuffle` which is a more elegant way of doing that last method (unique characters) but I'm not convinced it's the most efficient way since it's likely to involve a lot of swaps to get a decent shuffle. The method here seems to me to be more likely to be faster.

Keep that in mind if performance is important, but also keep in mind that I haven't tested how good it is - it may be fast enough - it may even blow my solution out of the water :-) As with all performance-related things, *measure, don't guess.*

Comment: Honestly, based on my experience with PHP, I've arrived at a simple conclusion: the C-based library functions will inevitably be faster than anything you can write in PHP.  As such, I would expect the str_shuffle method to be faster, regardless of the noted inefficiency.  You're right though: if performance really matters,  measure, don't guess

Answer (score 1):

Here’s some example generator:

```
$length = 5;
$charset = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$str = '';
while ($length--) {
    $str .= $charset[rand() % count($charset)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php, in case you dislike hardcoding the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, for funsies. Could be shortened - here it's a bit verbose, for readability.

```
function rand_string($length=5) {
    $values = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"));
    shuffle($values);
    $values = array_flip($values);

    $string = implode(array_rand($lenght));
    return $string;
}
```